# React - what are the steps to get data from api and render it?

Tags: reactjs, axios, render

I am building a site just like stackoverflow.com. I want my home page to display top questions. For that, I have sample questions on the backed. Now, I want to display only the question and tags from the questions array.

The code is in the image [image: here]

I have made axios connection for that:

```
const instance = axios.create({

baseURL: "https://2w2knta9ag.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/dev", });

instance.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
```

To connect it, I wrote the command: `instance.get("/questions)`

Now, how do I display only the question and tags??

**EDIT:**

On using the code given bellow, my js file now becomes:

```
import React from 'react';
import instance from '../../api';
class QuestionList extends React {

  componentDidMount() {
     instance
     .get("/questions")
     .then((res) => {
       this.setState({ data: res.data });
      });
  }

  render () {
    const { data } = this.state; 
    return <div>
      {
        data && data.map(d => {
          return <div>question: {d.question}, tags: {d.tags}</div>;
        })
      }
    </div>
  }
}   
export default QuestionList;
```

But, this is just making my site in a loading state, and it gets hanged!!

Comment: This question is too broad. Please only ask about specific problems you're facing. It sounds like you'd be better off studying React and web development in general.

Comment: Yes, I am new to React

Comment: Instead of creating a complex site, it's a better idea to learn the basics first. React has a lot of different concepts, so don't try and run before you can walk.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to get an array only with the tags and the question. if so, you can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this

```
const questions = result.map(({ question, tags }) => ({ question, tags }))
```

Comment: how do i get it on my render function?

Comment: Do you know how to get the result into the render method?

Comment: I think it better if you learn some React before jumping so much forward

Answer (score 0):

First you export the axios instance so that it can be used from other components.
Now you can send the api request in `componentDidMount` and update your component's state with the data.
And in render function, you just get the value from state and display.

If you are new to react, learn React Hooks and know that `componentDidMount` method is the best place to send api requests.

For Example:

```
import React from 'react';
import instance from '../../api';

class QuestionList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        instance.get('/questions').then((res) => {
            this.setState({ data: res.data });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { data } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                {data &&
                    data.map((d) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                question: {d.question}, tags: {d.tags}
                            </div>
                        );
                    })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default QuestionList;
```

Comment: i followed this, but then my localhost is not showing anything

Comment: if you can explain the meaning of those curly braces where mapping is being done

Comment: i think you are quite basic to React.. it was just to show you how to use the data, you have to return something inside render() function. You can write javascript code between the curly braces

Comment: I followed your code, its showing me this error: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";" on componentDidMount(){...}

Comment: The code could have syntax issue :) just post it here if you dont think it's easy to fix

Comment: i fixed that issue, but upon npm start the site is just loading and not showing anything, and if i comment out the part written above, the site works fine

Comment: debug each step. does the api work? if then, state is updated correctly with the response, any other errors in console?

Comment: :) seriously, you have to learn something about react, i updated the answer according to your update